# Is there any double min normal variable in tcl to compare float numbers?

Tags: compare, double, tcl

I want to compare two values(float) if they are same in tcl. This we can directly do with = operator and additionally is there any way to compare very small difference also. Following is the incomplete code because of in tcl I could not find the **Tcl_Float_MIN_NORMAL**.

```
proc floatequal {a b {epsilon ""}} {
  if {[string is double -strict $a] && [string is double -strict $b]} {
    set diff [expr {$a -$b}]

    # handles infinities
    if {$a == $b} { 
      set ret 1;
    } elseif {$a == 0 || $b == 0 || $diff < $Tcl_Float_MIN_NORMAL} {
      # a or b is zero or both are extremely close to it
      # relative error is less meaningful here
      set ret [expr {$diff < ($epsilon * $Tcl_Float_MIN_NORMAL)}];
    } else { 
      # use relative error
      set ret [expr {$diff / ($a + $b) < $epsilon}];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl does not define such a constant, but is defined to use IEEE double precision arithmetic, which in turn defines MIN_NORMAL as `2.2250738585072014e-308` which is 2<sup>-1022</sup>. If you prefer to calculate the value, try `expr {2.**-1022}`; note that Tcl does conversion of provably-constant subexpressions to literals internally, so using the computed form incurs no significant cost. Also note that Tcl takes great care to get conversion between strings and double-precision floats both right (including the evil edge cases!) and parsimonious (so the shortest strings are used) so the conversion can be regarded as safe.

The *only* place that single-precision floats occur in Tcl is in the `binary format` and `binary scan` commands, and then only in order to allow those sorts of values to be placed into a binary structure…

---

Your line:

```
set diff [expr $a -$b]
```

is not safe at all, as it can perform double substitution of both `$a` and `$b`. This is not what you meant, and Tcl's careful to ensure that it is not what you need. What you *really* want is this:

```
set diff [expr {$a - $b}]
```

The braces allow full compilation of the expression.